# Increment the last digit of a number

Tags: vb.net, numbers, format, increment, significant-digits

VB2010 I have a user form where the user inputs a number format. The routine then cycles through a list of number pairs and displays them in a list of categories:

```
 User format "0.00"
                            0.00 - 164.04
                            164.04 - 410.10
                            410.10 - 820.21
```

What I am trying to do is to increment the first value by one digit so there is no overlap. something like:

```
                            0.00 - 164.04
                            164.05 - 410.10
                            410.11 - 820.21
```

I am trying to make it so it works with any number format the user inputs like "0.000" or "0.0". What I currently have is (example for value 164.04)

```
1. Convert the value to a string "164.04"
2. Take the right most character "4" and convert to an integer 4
3. Increment the integer value by 1 to get 5
4. Take the characters in the string from step #1 except the last and then append
   the integer from Step #3 as a string to get "164.05".
```

Seemed to work in my VB6 program but wanted to see if anyone had any better ideas. I also don't think i accounted for the last digit being a 9.

Update: based on the suggestions below what ended up working for positive and negative numbers and integers and floats was the following:

```
Dim p As Integer
Dim numAsStr As String = num.ToString(fmt)
If numAsStr.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then
    p = 0
Else
    p = numAsStr.Length - numAsStr.IndexOf(".") - 1
End If
Dim result as Double = ((num* (10 ^ p) + 1.0) / (10 ^ p))
```

Comment: use a numericupdown and set the min for series 2 to be .01 more than the max for series 1 and so forth

Comment: The format is user input so it can be anything from "0.0" to "0.000000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the algorithm:

1.Find decimal points (p)

2.multiply the number by 10^p, increase it by one, divide it back by 10^p

```
Dim numAsStr As String = num.ToString()
Dim p As Integer = numAsStr.Length - numAsStr.IndexOf(".") - 1
Dim numInt as Integer = 10^p * num
Dim result as Double = ((10^p *num + 1.0) / 10^p).ToString()
```

Comment: ok am testing now. It works with some tweaks. Its important to add the intended format in Dim numAsStr As String = num.ToString("0.000") or whatever that may be.

Comment: Also to deal with the format being "0" or "0." where the result is an integer I split up into two cases.  If numAsStr.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then Dim result As Double = minVal + 1 and then the other case is as you wrote it.

Comment: @sinDizzy please look at the edited answer. It is completely updated.

Comment: ok let me take a look but doesn't that just omit the formatting like "0.000".

Comment: You need to take care of formatting when converting it to a String, e.g. Console.WriteLine (result.ToString("0.000"))

Comment: @sinDizzy Okay I think by 0.000 you mean cases like 10.100. In this case the original answer is the best choice I think. Especially since some rounding errors in Log lead to wrong results in some cases.

Comment: the log function craps when the value is zero. i think it was working how you suggested one revision back with my tweaks.

Comment: well yes the user will ionput a format string like "0.0" or "0.00000". My algorithm needs to adjust for that. looking at your prior suggestion that works the best. let me test a bit more.

Comment: some tweaks I made and this works. first I added the user specific format and second I split into the case where the result has no decimal point or is an integer.                                     Dim p As Integer Dim numAsStr As String = num.ToString(fmt) If numAsStr.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then p = 0 Else p = numAsStr.Length - numAsStr.IndexOf(".") - 1 End If Dim result as Double = ((num * (10 ^ p) + 1.0) / (10 ^ p))

Comment: That works for negative and positive numbers and for almost every formatting string I have input. It can be taken further since the point may not be the decimal separator like in some European countries but for me its only for internal usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ON ERROR RESUME NEXT" construct for this problem.

Comment: That will just ignore errors.  Why use that when .NET provides try/catch blocks for better error handling?